# Download only binary differences to the client with Google Drive SDK

Tags: google-drive-api

I would like to ask you if it is possible to download only binary differences between an old local file and one of the newer file versions on the server, and apply these to the file on the client ?

The scenario is the following:
There are multiple revisions of a single file on the drive.

A client with an outdated revision of a file connects to the drive and wants to update the file to some of the newer revisions. However, it only wants to transfer as little data as possible and apply these changes locally to its revision.

Is there any API call that can be used for this? I am specifically interested in Java-based functionality.

Dropbox' client support this, however its API doesn't. There is also BUP that can be used in a similar fashion, though it lacks cloud backend and proper Windows/Java support.

Thank you and kind regards
Peter

Answer (score 3):

Currently the Google Drive API does not support diff uploads. Though it is something we might consider in a future release. Thanks for the feature request :)

Comment: I think that support of diff uploads/downloads are very needed to compete with other services(ect dropbox). Hoping to see this in the future.